# Sort out dimensions listed incorrectly/only keep data in a certain format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a list of around 1500 items with dimensions, but the dimensions do not all have the same format. The dimensions I want to keep are listed as L x W x H. How can I sort the dimensions listed like this from the stuff I don't want (some are listed as only L x H, Diameter, or just gibberish, etc.) Thank you.

Comment: normally, you would need to write some code or formula. Then, if the code or formula doesn't work, you show it to us, explaining why it doesn't fit your needs. Then you can get someone to look at your question. As it is, it looks like you're asking us to write your code....

Answer (score 0):

If by *gibberish* you mean text values that could include *<space>x<space>* then you have some real problems. However, it it can be reasonable assumed that the  L x W x H format is what you want and the only values that contain 2 occurrences of *<space>x<space>* are valid ones then a helper column would identify the valid entries.

In an unused column to the right put this formula into the second row.

`=ISNUMBER(FIND(" x ", $A2, FIND(" x ", $A2) + 3))`

Fill down as necessary. The results should resemble the image below.

[image: True dimensions]

Use Data ► Sort & Filter ► Filter to filter your Helper column for FALSE. These entries can be deleted and when you turn the filter off you will be ;left with valid entries.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @jeeped's answer, if you are dealing with data from an external source, you might want to relax your rules to allow other valid input formats:

- There must be exactly three numbers, all non-negative integers.
- A decimal point is allowed, but no digits after the decimal point.
- They can be separated by "x" or "X" or "*".
- They can have extra spaces before, after or between the numbers, but not between the digits.

That would mean these values would all be OK:

```
    17x12x13
    100 * 50 * 2
    100. X 200. X 300
```

Problems of this sort are ideally suited to regular expressions. The RegExp feature can be added in Code editor with *Tools > References*, then check *"Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions"*. Then try this VBA function:

```
    Public Function IsNxNxN(s As String) As Boolean
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "^\s*(\d+)\.?\s*[xX*]\s*(\d+)\.?\s*[xX*]\s*(\d+)\.?\s*$"
        With .Execute(s)
            IsNxNxN = (.Count = 1)
        End With 
    End With
    End Function
```

In jeeped's sample worksheet, you would replace the B2 formula with:

```
    =IsNxNxN(A2)
```

If you are trying to clean up the data as well as filter it, you could use this:

```
    Public Function CleanupNxNxN(s As String) As String
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "^\s*(\d+)\.?\s*[xX*]\s*(\d+)\.?\s*[xX*]\s*(\d+)\.?\s*$"
        With .Execute(s)
            If .Count = 1 Then
                With .Item(0)
                    CleanupNxNxN = .SubMatches(0) & " x " & _
                                   .SubMatches(1) & " x " & _
                                   .SubMatches(2)
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With
    End Function
```

and set the formula for C2 to:

```
    =CleanupNxNxN(A2)
```

Any dimension values that are invalid will report False in column B and blank in Column C.  Valid dimensions such as `"  10.  x  20X30  "` would be reformatted as `"10 x 20 x 30"`.

If you would like to allow extra "gibberish" before or after the dimensions, you could remove the `"^"` and `"&"` anchor characters from `.Pattern`, and get:

```
    "approx. Size: 10*20*30 feet"     would yield:     True,   "10 x 20 x 30"
```